# Shader on disabled object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

[image]

Hi unity peoples
I found this effect (disabled greyed out) while looking for something in the hierarchy panel
I like it! - How would it be possible to add this kind of effect to game objects in game.
are there any easy to implement solutions.

is it possible to use what unity is doing here in game?
for example - on a locked item?

I'm not even sure what to search for. If this is a shader, or how this would be working.

```
void OnItemEnabled()
{
?
}
```

Some experiments so far
Using a lit shader, it however loses details, and seems to need a way of pulling the colours out of the current shaders to maintain all the details
[image: A lit shader]

How I would like the monkey to look if locked

[image]

I made a grey scale shader... but it's a bit dark
Not sure how to lighten it to match the look of "unity"

[image]

My final solution is here:
Shader code is here, with slider-bar to adjust brightness :

[image]

```
Shader "Custom/GreyScale"
{
Properties
{
[PerRendererData] _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
_EffectAmount("Effect Amount", Range(0, 10)) = 1.0
}

SubShader{
Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
LOD 200

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert

uniform float _EffectAmount;
sampler2D _MainTex;
struct Input {
float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
o.Albedo = (c.r + c.g + c.b) / 3 * _EffectAmount;
o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
//Fallback "Transparent/VertexLit"
}
```

My solution here - code is above.

[image: My solution here]

***Swapping materials on unlock***

Also I found this solution only solved half the problem, I had planned to swap shaders (but found this to be a no-no) so my solution for that is here
[Creating an unlockable game asset, writing a simple class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082587/creating-an-unlockable-game-asset-writing-a-simple-class)

With thanks
N

Comment: Pretty sure that if you just remove the texture, use a lit shader and set the color to white/gray - you should get similar results. You can simply change the materials of the `MeshRenderer` on the fly

Comment: Thanks Ron, I have tried your suggestion; it seems to lose too much detail if I go that way - Hopefully there is a way to work with the colour channels?... or some such to keep the colour graduations but force it to grey scale... which would be useful as most of these objects are multi material procedural colours - some have maps... so replacing these to the correct part of the mesh might be complicated...

Comment: try using grayscale color

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I made a grey scale shader, but I would like to brighten it a little more - half way there :)

Comment: ```o.Albedo = (c.r + c.g + c.b) / 3 * intensityMultiplier;``` try adding this and make ```intensityMultiplier;``` editable from editor and it can't be lower then **1**.

Comment: Thanks Ankit you put me on the right path, so I added a slider to the shader and quite happy with the result! Cheers!.

Comment: Cheers man, good luck ahead. Can you recommend me any place to learn shader development, I already know a little bit about shaders but all is from Amplify Shader Editor asset from the unity asset store. but don't know much about coding my own shader.

Comment: Thanks Anit, hmm i'd try brackeys or some YouTube TBH what I know about shaders fits on my little finger ;P 
Happy journeys in unity :) and thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqDOirux0Es

Comment: As it turns out I can't swap the shader runtime... so now I have a differnt question ;P
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078281/how-to-fix-normals-on-shader